# Square distance function defined on a compact Surface.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $S$ be a surface and $p_{0} \in S$ fixed. Define $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(p) = |p-p_0|^2$ for every $p \in S$. If $S$ is compact, then $f$ has at least a critical point.

Here is my try:

Given $p \in S$, there is a parametrization $X: U \to \mathbb{R}^3$ s.t.  $p \in X(U) = V_{p}$, where $V_{p}$ is an open set of $S$. Hence, we can cover $S$ by these open sets,

$$
S = \bigcup_{p \in S} V_{p}.
$$

Since $S$ is compact, then there are $p_{i} \in S$, $i = 1, \dots, n$, s.t. $S = \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_{p_{i}}$. This is how I think the assumption of compactness play a role in the exercise. To prove that $f$ has at least a critical point, I've been reasoning by contradiction. Let us assume that $f$ hasn't a critical point. Then the set $X = \{p \in S: (\forall v \in T_{p}S)(\langle v, p-p_{0} \rangle) \neq 0 \}$ is non-empty. Thus, there exists $q \in X$ s.t. $q \in V_{pi}$ for some $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$. From here I don't know how to carry to a contradiction.

I'll be very grateful with your help.

Comment: Hint: $f$ is continuous on $S$ compact, and thus has extremal points. Note that there is an obvious minimum

Comment: Yes. I was a bit confused about if I could use this result since the domain is a surface. My doubt arises because of abstracting the definitions and results from the calculus on Euclidean space to the world of surfaces, but that is another thing. Here $S$ is just seen as a subset of ${R}^3$. Thank you so much.